# returning int array when return type is int *

Tags: c

I have a function that is described like this

```
int * oddNumbers(l, r, int* result_size){
   static int res[r-l];
   int index = 0;
   while(l < r){
      if(l % 2 != 0){
         res[index] = l;
         index++;
      }
      l++;

   }
   result_size = &index;
   return res;
}
```

it is a problem question I have been given to solve. What I don't understand is how to return an integer array. I have looked up multiple ways to do this. Declaring the variable static, and allocating memory for the variable.

I know the industry method for doing this is allowing the caller to allocate memory for the return value. But, unfortunately I do not have access to that part of the program only this function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just do this `return integer_1D_array_name`. and func has return type `int*`.

Comment: it is already doing it...

Comment: `result_size = &index;` ===> `*result_size = index;`

Comment: `static int res[r-l];` is not allowed.

Comment: The problem, as @dasblinkenlight alluded, is that a static array can't be a VLA. It doesn't make sense, since the array is allocated just once, not every time the function is called, so the size can't depend on variables.

Comment: So, then I simply do not know how to solve this problem then. The array size that is return isn't a constant value. And the only way I can return it is through a static declaration otherwise it'll be popped of the stack. Can someone help me understand how to solve this then?

Comment: You can use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()`.

Comment: You can pre-allocate a large chunk of static memory, parcel out pieces from it, and keep track of the current "watermark" for allocating additional chunks.

Comment: time to learn about [dynamic memory allocation](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=qXShWt_RPIff0gK4uqSoDQ&q=c+dynamic+memory+allocation&oq=c+dynamic+memory+allocation&gs_l=psy-ab.3...677.4227.0.4494.27.15.0.0.0.0.284.1092.0j2j3.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..22.5.1090...0.0.BZ4ht7UfNvY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is commonly solved with dynamic memory allocation.

In rare scenarios when you do not have access to `malloc`/`free`, you can roll your own memory allocator. Here is an "allocate-only" example that produces pointers up to a specific pre-allocation limit:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 65536

int * oddNumbers(int l, int r, int* result_size){
    static int raw[MAX_SIZE];
    static int* current = raw;
    int size = r-l;
    // Make sure that allocation size is positive
    if (size <= 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // Make sure we have enough available memory remaining in raw[]
    ptrdiff_t available = &raw[MAX_SIZE] - current;
    if (available < size) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // Allocate "size" elements from raw
    int *res = current;
    current += size;
    int index = 0;
    while(l < r){
        if(l % 2 != 0){
            res[index++] = l;
        }
        l++;
    }
    return res;
}
```